# How to color the area under the curve in Bokeh?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, bokeh

I wanted to color the area under the step curve where my x axis is datetime, I've tried the patch but it provides color between the curves and not under the curve. Is there any better way to color the area under the curve?

[image: plot]

Here is the code:

```
output_file("layout.html")
df = pd.read_csv( 'file')
df.day= df.day.apply(lambda x : parser.parse(x))
s = []
p_energy_patch = figure(title='graph', plot_width=1000, plot_height=300, x_axis_type="datetime")
p_energy_patch.step(x = df.day, y = df['total'], line_width=2, color="black", alpha=0.8)
p_energy_patch.patch(df.day, df['total'], color = "black",alpha=0.5, line_width=2)
tab2 = Panel(child=p_energy_patch, title="Normal+Patch(WH)")
tabs = Tabs(tabs=[ tab2])
s.append(tabs)
result = column(s)
show(result)
```

Comment: I think you can use patch. But instead two curves, convert the below curve into a straight line, or... do you want to color under the curve to infinity and beyond! :O

Comment: yes I've more than 2 curves, you can say approx. 5-6.

Comment: If you show some image in your question would help to let us know what you want to achieve

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpqSD.png, in this blue line shows the step graph and black the patches, here the patches are not fully covering the step graph

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok, here is the code for your reference